# android picture loading progress update parent view

Tags: android, image, listview, progress, invalidation

I'm a bit new in android developement and have got issue with updating view which I cannot resolve myself.

What I've got is mapview, on the map I have sliding drawer with listview. The list view is build up by custom adapter which puts some texts and uses imageLoader object to load picture from url in backround. In the listview row layout I have got also progresloader placed in relative view on top of picture. This is default visible and is put GONE on imageloader backround thread when loaded picture is put to imageview.
So you get the idea, it is to show progres of loading picture and loading them on backround to have listview built up quickly.

To my problem. The sliding drawer is customized to show part of it (1 item from list +  a little from next) when closed and full screen when opened. When user click on map icon where there are more items under it, it loads up listview in closed sliding drawer. The progres loader in it is not rotating, when I open sliding drawer, loading progresses are rotating, they are rotating also when moving drawer and they are rotating also when drawer is closed and there is any interaction with ui like moving map or so. 
Was trying to figure out what to do, found out that when I add invalidate of content on dispatch draw on sliding drawer that makes it to refresh sliding drawer again and to fire dispatch draw again, loading progresses in lstview are rotating but this is not very good as basically I created infinite loop and updating sliding drawer forever, this uses up all cpu. 
Updating sliding drawer or listview should be triggered by progress loaders but it is somehow not ;o( It does work well on open drawer and also on closed but I have to interact with UI than it fires dispatch draw on slider which redraws it children and porgresses ar erotating. 
Can someone give me a clue how to make the drawer to update when loaders are there visible?
thanks a lot.